# Routing controllers in .Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a folder admin inside controller folder and wrote few controllers in it. I want to access all functions in that controllers in that folder by a url like abc.com/admin//.

I can get it working directly when its put directly in controller folder.

**EDIT**

WHAT HAVE YOU TRIED?

- Just created a folder and wrote normal controllers in it. But I don't know how to route it.

Comment: Great, what is your question and [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: you should try Areas in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i would suggest, rather than just creating a folder and create controllers inside of it. You should create an `Area` 
When you create an `Area` in asp.net mvc, it will automatically create folders(controller, model etc) for you. And the routing setup as well.
For more info, please visit 
http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/article.php/c20227/Using-Areas-in-ASPNET-MVC-Application.htm

Comment: how do i use roles in web.config to prevent access to a particular Area

Comment: You have to do that in the controller by just add the attribute [Authorize]

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601420/asp-net-mvc-role-based-access-to-controller

Answer (score 1):

Add a route for the admin controllers in your route config if you want to support that path in the URL.  Something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But @DotNetDreamer is right that Areas are a better solution for the admin functionality of your site.

Comment: Then all @Html.ActionLink will leads to admin subfolder